# The number of Maximal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

G is  a finite p-group.and N is the number of maximal proper subgroups of G.then 
N is congruent to 1 mod p.

I showed that every maximal proper subgroup is normal in G.
please could you help me to complete my answer to this question.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It's doubtful this is the intended solution, so I leave this as a comment. Solve the problem for elementary abelian $p$-groups ($\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$ maximal subgroups for the elementary abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$). Then, note that the quotient $G/\Phi(G)$ is elementary abelian and that there is a one-to-one correspondence between maximal subgroups of $G$ and maximal subgroups of $G/\Phi(G)$.